# How to get correctly filter and get object which types equal to "administrative_area_level_1"

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

This is the sample address object array

I want to get objects which  types are equal to "administrative_area_level_1"

```
 let Address=  [
        {
            "long_name": "545",
            "short_name": "545",
            "types": [
                "street_number"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Station Street",
            "short_name": "Station St",
            "types": [
                "route"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Box Hill",
            "short_name": "Box Hill",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Whitehorse City",
            "short_name": "Whitehorse",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_2",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Victoria",
            "short_name": "VIC",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                "political"
            ]
        },
    ]
```

The expected result should be

```
  {
            "long_name": "Victoria",
            "short_name": "VIC",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                "political"
            ]
        }
```

I tried  this.Address.filter(d => d["types"] ==
> "administrative_area_level_1") and it not worked

Comment: Change your filter callback to use: `d.types.includes("administrative_area_level_1")`

Comment: @Nick Can't use includes in typescript 
tried this .filter(d => d["types"].includes("administrative_area_level_1"));  but it gives compile error

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Address.filter(d => d.types.some(v => v == "administrative_area_level_1"))
```

or if you want only one match:

```
this.Address.find(d => d.types.some(v => v == "administrative_area_level_1"))
```